# login based forward proxy control for mac os x 10.6?

Tags: mac-osx-server

Can I do user/login based forward proxy (for website blocking) in Mac OS X server 10.6, or know of a solution that will integrate with the Open Directory of OSX?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any proxy will allow you to block sites and force authentication of clients against a directory .

Probably the best know proxy is Squid (http://www.squid-cache.org/), it will run on OS X or Linux and it will allo users to authenticate against [LDAP/RADIUS/Kerberos](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Authentication).

The nice chaps at AFP 548 even have a guide on how to [integrate Squid with OD](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20040903184124948).

The same principles (LDAP/RADIUS/Kerberos) will allow you to use virtually any Proxy with OD.